# How can I get boot menu up to install on mini 9 from flash

Tags: installation

I am starting to install 12.10 from a USB on my mini 9.  Instructions say to hit F12 to bring up the boot menu but the mini 9 does not have an f12.  Anyone know how I can get the boot menu up to start this?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Some Dell Mini 9 forums say to hold 0 (zero) right when you power on to get the boot menu.

At the beginning of your boot, hit F2 to enter BIOS settings. Once in BIOS, go to the Boot menu and make sure "USB Storage" will boot before your hard drive (higher up in the list means boot first). It should look something like this.[image]

or this[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get into the bios by pressing "Esc" and "alt" simultaneously